# Using tikzDevice in lyx doesn't work

Tags: r, latex, knitr, lyx, tikz

I am trying to include a histogram created with `qplot(ggplot2)` with the code chunk

```
<<histAge, echo = F, message = F, warning = F, dev='tikz'>>=
  plot(hist.age)
@
```

It works just fine with `dev='pdf'`, but doesn't work with `dev='tikz'`. The library `tikzDevice` is installed in R, `tikz` is included in the `lyx` document.

In case it matters, `hist.age` is a `qplot` with `geom` histogram.

The message in lyx says somewhere

> Error in system(latexCmd, intern = T, ignore.stderr = T) : 'C:\Program' not found".
>
> Overall error is Error: Cannot convert file.

I would really appreciate any help to make this work!

Comment: Looks like a problem with spaces. I am guessing this issue is Windows-specific. If you have access to Ubuntu, my guess is it would work there. Please post a bug report *with a .lyx minimal example*. Please read this for more information: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: should I report this to lyx, knitr or tikzDevice?

Comment: Not sure. If you post a minimal example (see link above), I can give you my guess with whether I think it is a bug and what the root cause is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be an issue that [has been reported](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/99) earlier this year. Before the next version of **tikzDevice** (`> 0.8.1`) is on CRAN, you need to install the development version:

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/tikzDevice')
```

Since you are on Windows, you will need [RTools](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/).